# How do i make my pickNum array just one index instead of 3 different indexes.

Tags: actionscript-3

this will random my numPool and push the random three numbers to my array called pickNum. I need that pickeNum to be just one index instead of three indexes. Thanks and i will appreciate any help thanks.

```
var numPool:Array = [1,2,3];
var pickNum:Array = [];
var randomCount:Number = 3;
var r:Number;


for (var i = 0; i < randomCount; i++)
{
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * numPool.length);
    pickNum[pickNum.length] = numPool.splice(r,1);
}

trace("Number Picked " + pickNum);
```

Comment: Please re-read your question, it makes little sense. You say *"push the random three numbers to my array called pickNum"*.  Then you say *"I need that array to be just one index"*.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I completely understand what you are saying, but the issue with the code above is that splice returns an Array containing the values that were spliced from the array. Also, would be easiest to just do a push. So the proper line for getting that value and pushing it into the pickNum array would be :

```
pickNum.push(numPool.splice(r,1).pop());
```

And if you are saying that you want only 1 random number from the pool, then why do you need a loop ?

Comment: I will use all three numbers from the numPool array.. i was told that the loop will help me randomize the numbers but i might be wrong.. i am new to AS3 and coding in general and i am slowly learning thanks for the help..

Comment: You need to state your goal, in a plain and simple way. For example : I have an array of numbers, and I want to pick a random number from that array.  Then someone can help you achieve your goal. You have not clearly stated what you want to do, so it's unlikely that anyone will help you.